# Optimize MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have two tables 1.category 2. product tables.I want total products under a category,total sub-products under a category with author who last created the product or sub-product under product along with create date.

My Query is working like below:

```
SELECT c.category_id,c.title,c.type,c.alias,
    (SELECT COUNT(product_id) 
     FROM products 
     WHERE parent_type='main' 
     AND category_id=c.category_id 
     AND is_active=1
    ) as total_main_products,
    (SELECT count(product_id) 
     FROM products 
     WHERE parent_type IN('subtypeL1','subtypeL2','subtypeL3') 
     AND category_id=c.category_id 
     AND is_active=1
    ) as total_sub_products,
    DATE_FORMAT(
        (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(created) as update_time 
         FROM products 
         WHERE parent_type='main' 
         AND category_id=c.category_id 
         ORDER BY update_time desc limit 1 
        ),'%b %d,%Y at %r'
    )as last_updated,
    (SELECT user_id
     FROM products 
     WHERE parent_type='main' 
     AND category_id= c.category_id 
     ORDER BY created desc limit 1 
    ) as updated_by 
FROM category c 
WHERE c.type=1 
AND c.is_active=1 
ORDER BY c.created DESC
```

Looking for a discussion , Is this the right & efficient way to write query or we have any other way to get the same result.I tried JOIN options but not returning the correct result.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: To have **any** hope of getting help, you've got to format your query - get some linefeeds and indentation in there

Comment: I second @Bohemian. I've done some reformatting for free. Next time I'll send you the bill ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (without last `updated_by` field) -

```
SELECT c.category_id, c.title, c.type, c.alias,
  COUNT(IF(p.parent_type='main' AND p.is_active = 1, p.product_id, 0)) total_main_products,
  COUNT(IF((p.parent_type='subtypeL1' OR p.parent_type='subtypeL2' OR p.parent_type='subtypeL3') AND p.is_active = 1, p.product_id, 0)) total_sub_products,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(IF(p.parent_type='main', update_time, 0))) last_updated -- add formatting here
FROM category c
  LEFT JOIN products p
    ON p.category_id = c.category_id 
WHERE
  c.type = 1 AND c.is_active = 1
GROUP BY
  p.category_id
ORDER BY
  c.created DESC
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your response , but this query returns the wrong result as my other JOIN query is returning

Comment: Please tell what is wrong. Provide an example with table definitions, small dataset and desired result.